# YAMLSyntaxError: Failed to resolve SEQ_ITEM node here at line X, column Y:

Tags: yaml, netlify-cms, gridsome

I'm getting this error when trying to run Netlify CMS

```
Error loading the CMS configuration
Config Errors:

YAMLSyntaxError: Failed to resolve SEQ_ITEM node here at line 10, column 1:

    - name: Posts
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^…

Check your config.yml file.
```

I have checked the syntax and tried different syntax but I still get the same error for somewhere in the `config.yml` document.

This is the troubled config.yml document:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master

media_folder: src/assets/images
media_library:
    name: uploads

collections:
    - name: Posts
      label: Posts
      create: true
      folder: "/articles"
      slug: articles/{{slug}}
      fields:
        - {label: Title, name: title, widget: string}
        - {label: Publish Date, name: date, widget: datetime}
        - {label: Featured Image, name: cover_image, widget: image}
        - {label: Body, name: body, widget: markdown}
```

Here is a link to the files that I am getting the errors from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OJPKJRgCljxAG5UuUxXkBPPNoUcyJe48/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `label` and `create` and the following items must be at the same indentation level as `name`. Why did you indent it more?

Comment: that must have been something that StackOverflow did because even with the fixed indents i am still getting the error

Comment: Welcome Brett.  From a YAML standpoint, this looks fine, but the error message mentioning line 10 column **1** suggests there might be something wrong with the indentation.   Copying it out of your post however, that seems OK.   It might help if you can zip the file and edit your question to attach it, that way if there is anything funny in the file, we get an exact copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you linked uses tabs for indentation. YAML uses spaces, see [the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534):

> In general, indentation is defined as a zero or more space characters at the start of a line.
>
> To maintain portability, tab characters must not be used in indentation, since different systems treat tabs differently.

You need to convert the tabs to spaces.